# Android cannot remove bottom margin from list view items

Tags: android, list, layout

[image]I have been searching all through Stack and I can't seem to find anything that helps. I have made list views 200000 times.. I have a simple list view and no matter what I DO there is a bottom margin. even got rid of all my subviews and jsut had the main relativelayout in the list and no luck. My xml is as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android1:id="@+id/listItem"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:height="70dp"
   >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/daysHolder"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:background="@color/orange"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"

    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daysAway"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6"

        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/days"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="Roboto"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Days"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"

    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BandName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Distance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EventDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/eventLocation"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BandName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"

        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as you can see its nothing out of the ordinary. But no matter what i have a 20px margin below each list item.

Am I doing somehting funky in my xml?

this is my listview activity xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context=".ListView" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="0dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/listlocal" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/localShows"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#eaeaea"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="0dp" >
        </ListView>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide an image so we can all see

Comment: of the spaces inbetween?

Answer (score 0):

Why have you added this code?

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

just remove it, it is useless.

Now, the answer. Your "marbin bottom" is your Distance textVew. It is below the EventDate textView. Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/BandName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/EventDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Distance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/EventDate"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="9sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

do not forget to add your margins